# Postgre/SQLAlchemy UUID inserts but failed to compare

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, uuid

I am accessing Postgre database using SQLAlchemy models. In one of models I have Column with UUID type.

```
id = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), default=uuid.uuid4(), nullable=False, unique=True)
```

and it works when I try to insert new row (generates new id).
Problem is when I try to fetch Person by id I try like

```
person = session.query(Person).filter(Person.id.like(some_id)).first()
```

some_id is string received from client
but then I get `error LIKE (Programming Error) operator does not exist: uuid ~~ unknown`.

How to fetch/compare UUID column in database through SQLAlchemy ?

Comment: Are you sure your uuid is unique? Because from what I see, you should omit the braces in `default`: `default=uuid.uuid4`.

Comment: @javex: very good point. Also, does it really make sense to use `like` with `uuid`? Why not just `.filter(Person.id==some_guid).first()` or even `session.query(Person).get(some_guid)` ?

Comment: @van I am getting  from client string and I need to find in database Person with same id, I tried with == but id doesn't work. With liek works when I am using mysql but I wanted to switch to postgre like http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/types.html GUID I am using (also tried with postgre base dialects)

Answer (score 0):

don't use like, use `=`, not `==` (in ISO-standard SQL, `=` means equality).

Keep in mind that UUID's are stored in PostgreSQL as binary types, not as text strings, so `LIKE` makes no sense.  You could probably do `uuid::text LIKE ?` but it would perform very poorly over large sets because you are effectively ensuring that indexes can't be used.

But `=` works, and is far preferable:

```
mydb=>select 'd796d940-687f-11e3-bbb6-88ae1de492b9'::uuid = 'd796d940-687f-11e3-bbb6-88ae1de492b9';
 ?column? 
----------
 t
(1 row)
```